# How to translate a string to object notation

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm working with a JSON validator that checks a give JSON object against a schema and returns errors if it doesn't match. One of the things I need to do is add missing attributes, but these could potentially be quite deep in the structure. The validator error returns the location of a missing attribute as a string in this format:

```
'data.thing1.thing2.thingN'
```

I can strip out the "data." bit easily enough, but I don't know how to translate the rest to correct object notation, in any depth. This is what I've got so far:

```
var attributeLineage = newField.split(".");
obj[attributeLineage[0]][attributeLineage[1]] = "";
```

So obviously this only works when there are only two levels of depth. I need to loop through the values in `attributeLineage` and link them all together to correctly construct the missing attribute in the given object, at any depth. How can this be done?

I might be missing something totally obvious, or going about it the wrong way, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method get the reference of the inner object and update the property using last element in split array.

```js
var newField = 'data.thing1.thing2.thingN';
// split the string
var attributeLineage = newField.split("."),
  // get last element and remove it from splitted array
  prop = attributeLineage.pop();

var ob = {
  data: {}
};

// get the object reference
var obj = attributeLineage.reduce(function(o, k) {
  // return if nested object is defined 
  // else define and return it
  return o[k] || (o[k] = {}) && o[k];
}, ob);

// update the inner object property
obj[prop] = "hi";

console.log(ob);
```

Comment: I'm a bit stumped by this approach (though it's more helpful than the linked 'duplicate' answer). I thought you were creating ob as a test, but I don't think that's what you're doing? I have an existing object where the missing attribute needs to be appended. When I try your approach, o[k] is often undefined and obj always ends up undefined.

I think the issue is that I need to append an attribute, not just fill in a value to an existing attribute.

Comment: Ah cool! I had to change the return value of the reduce to: return o[k] || (o[k] = "") && o[k];, since the end attributes are never objects themselves, and left off this bit: obj[prop] = "";

Comment: @KatharineOsborne : end attribute from the split array is removed using `pop()` , so there is no need for that